# powerbi using datetime cumulative measure: RE how long has the tap been running

Tags: time, powerbi, dax

I am trying to find the time cumulative total using datetime column and value column to find out how long two taps have been running - I would like the final result to tell me tap A has been running 6 Hours today, or 120 hours this month, or 300 hours running the last 6 months.

I have tried to use the calculate function and I'm stuck as to how I will include the datetime column as when I do, the value I get is not the correct value.

datetime
1/11/2019 00:15:23, value = 37 eg, so I have 1000+ rows across a few months, with datetime value every couple of seconds, some of the datetime timestamps have zero value.

Any help would be much appreciated

thank you

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your data and the expected result based on that data sample? Why do you mention a value column and a value of 37? What is the relevance of that? If you want to figure out a duration, you need a start time stamp and a stop time stamp for each event, Do you have such data?

Comment: Hi @teylyn, thanks for the reply....I meant to show that on this date and time the value was 37, so the tap speed was 37. I don't have a start and end time, in two separate columns, I only have once column of continuous date time stamps and the corresponding value at that time, hence why I was thinking it's a cumulative time figure I'm trying to achieve - okay I'll try and attach some data

Comment: How long has the tap been running for a value of 37??? You want to show duration, but you only have time stamps for start time???